# Google map изменить цвет точки положения пользователя

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Я никак не могу найти информацию о том как изменить цвет голубой точки показывающей положение пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реально ли это вообще сделать?

Comment: К сожалению официального пути не существует еще пока, но можно сделать костыльно.

Comment: Жаль, что так. Костылить не очень хотелось.